# How to change download url path in wordpress to www.yoursite.com/download?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to hide or shorten the link to files or picture uploaded to the wp-content/uploads folder.
By default in WordPress if you upload and image, pdf, etc and insert it into a post or page it will have a link like this:

mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/picture.jpg"

I want to hide the reference to all WP folders on my site. I am trying to find a way that the URL will display like this instead.

mysite.org/uploads/2014/08/picture.jpg"

or

mysite.org/uploads/picture.jpg"

or

mysite.org/picture.jpg"

Is there a plugin or some hack that will let me hide the "wp-content" from showing up in my urls?

Comment: This is moving rather than hiding but simple enough: http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Moving_uploads_folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your wp-config.php file for your website.

```
define( 'UPLOADS', 'downloads' );
```

Then using FTP or RDP (or however you access your server), create a folder called "downloads" in the root directory of the WordPress site.

Then you need to uncheck the box for the "Organize my uploads into month- and year-based folders" option in Settings > Media of the WordPress admin.

Note: If you already have files in the media library, those will need to be moved over and all references to the old uploads folder in the database changed, if you want it all to be consistent.