# How to change download path on wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, url, path

I did a website on WordPress, and it has a lot of pictures and pdf files for visitors, but I realized that when I click on a pdf link, it shows a complete path that I don't know how secure is it to show, and besides it doesn't look clean. It is the typical and by default www.mysite.cl/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/document.pdf

I would like it to be shorter, something like www.mysite.cl/downloads/document.pdf. And I found here something I think is a great answer and a way to do it without using plugins, but I have some doubts since I'm starting at this and don't know where to insert a code.

This is the answer: [How to change download url path in wordpress to www.yoursite.com/download?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29105782/how-to-change-download-url-path-in-wordpress-to-www-yoursite-com-download)

And my questions are:

1. Where do I put the new code `define( 'UPLOADS', 'downloads' );`? at the beginning, at the end, it's the same...?
2. I use a child theme, so I should move the php file to the child theme right?
3. I already have files in the media library, I must move them all to the new created download folder? English isn't my mother language, so I didn't understand quite good what he tried to said in this part of the explanation. By logic I think I must move all the files to the new folder, and I think that the new code "calls" the web to search in the new folder instead of looking in the old uploads folder... doesn't it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your questions:

1 - Yes, whether you enter in the beginning or the end ***(even before the line that says /That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging.)***, I recommend you set this constant in your `wp-config.php file`

2 - The child theme allows you to use a theme as a base, where you can customize the details of the parent theme without changing the original theme code. Then you just need to create the php files you want to overwrite.

3 - Yes, you need to move your files to the new folder, as well as change the references in your database. I recommend that you do not do this on a site already in production, but if you do, you will have to change the path in your database to the averages already sent.

Comment: Hello, thank you... what does it mean change references on the database? The site is already finished, with all information and files up. How can I change the path in the database? Is it really insecure the default path from wordpress?